# SQL with Case statement in where clause to reset the value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have multiple queries in the form of UNION

and for one of the query i need Case statement in where clause to make a check for value `@CategoryID` My condition is if @CategoryID <> 0 then @CategoryID = 0

Note: I cant pass `@CategoryID =0` as one of the statement in union needs the actual value.

I need to reset the `@CategoryID` only for last statement to 0 in case categoryid is not 0.

I tried using if statement that generates error & i also tried case statement in where clause that also generate error. I would appreciate help in this regard so that i can reset the `@CategoryID =0` for last sql statement in store procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetBannerByIDsAPICPL]
    @ArticleID int,
    @PageID int,
    @IssueID int,
    @CategoryID int,
    @BannerLayoutPosition int,
    @LangID int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    -- will show artile related banner
    SELECT BannerID, BannerName, '../images/Banners/' +BannerImageFile AS ImagePath,BannerURL,BannerLocation FROM Banner_Manager    
    WHERE ArticleID = @ArticleID    AND BannerLocation = @BannerLayoutPosition AND LanguageID=@LangID AND Active = 1 
    UNION ALL

    -- show banner by category & Issue
    SELECT BannerID, BannerName, '../images/Banners/' +BannerImageFile AS ImagePath ,BannerURL,BannerLocation FROM Banner_Manager   
    WHERE CategoryID = @CategoryID AND IssueID = @IssueID   AND BannerLocation = @BannerLayoutPosition 
    AND LanguageID=@LangID AND Active = 1 
        UNION ALL

    -- show banner by category 
    SELECT BannerID, BannerName, '../images/Banners/' +BannerImageFile AS ImagePath ,BannerURL,BannerLocation FROM Banner_Manager   
    WHERE CategoryID = @CategoryID  AND BannerLocation = @BannerLayoutPosition 
    AND LanguageID=@LangID AND Active = 1 
    UNION ALL
    -- will show page  related banner
    SELECT BannerID, BannerName, '../images/Banners/' +BannerImageFile AS ImagePath,BannerURL,BannerLocation FROM Banner_Manager    
    WHERE PageID = @PageID  AND BannerLocation = @BannerLayoutPosition AND LanguageID=@LangID AND Active = 1 
    UNION ALL
    --will show issue related banner
    -- Need To Check if @CategoryID is not 0 if it is not 0 then i have to set the @CategoryID = 0
    SELECT BannerID, BannerName, '../images/Banners/' +BannerImageFile AS ImagePath,BannerURL,BannerLocation FROM Banner_Manager    
    WHERE IssueID = @IssueID AND CategoryID = @CategoryID AND BannerLocation = @BannerLayoutPosition AND LanguageID=@LangID AND Active = 1 


END
```

Answer (score 0):

If this condition is only applicable on the last statement:

```
@CategoryID <> 0 then @CategoryID = 0
```

The why are you still passing the parameter with `@CategoryID` when the value you want to check will always zero?

On the last statement, why can you not directly compare category with zero:

```
-- will show issue related banner
SELECT  BannerID, 
        BannerName, 
        '../images/Banners/' + BannerImageFile AS ImagePath,
        BannerURL,
        BannerLocation 
FROM    Banner_Manager    
WHERE   IssueID = @IssueID AND 
        CategoryID = 0 AND      -- <<== HERE
        BannerLocation = @BannerLayoutPosition AND 
        LanguageID=@LangID AND 
        Active = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to set the @CategoryID to 0 in the union statement if you don't want it changed in that query.  Set it to 0 after in a separate statement:

```
UNION ALL
--will show issue related banner
-- Need To Check if @CategoryID is not 0 if it is not 0 then i have to set the @CategoryID = 0
SELECT BannerID, BannerName, '../images/Banners/' +BannerImageFile AS ImagePath,BannerURL,BannerLocation FROM Banner_Manager    
WHERE IssueID = @IssueID AND CategoryID = @CategoryID AND BannerLocation = @BannerLayoutPosition AND LanguageID=@LangID AND Active = 1 

SET @CategoryID = 0
```